# Foursquare Android app not correctly "catching" the checkin url/event

Tags: android, mobile, foursquare

If in an Android mobile you goto the mobile web page for a place to do a checkin:

e.g. https://foursquare.com/mobile/v/bcntouch/4e89646eb634306116691c16

Then when you click on the "Check-in here" link, the Android native app detects the url (via an Intent) and is started.

However, it closes immediately without showing any UI and you are left at the same web page, and the checking is NOT done.

If you disable the native apps ability to capture that url by default, and repeat the procedure (and chose the browser to complete the action, not the native Foursquare app), then the checkin will be done correctly.

This seems a Foursquare bug to me, as both the page and the app are from foursquare...

We use redirects from our web page to the venue page in Foursquare (as specified in Foursquare API docs). That in turn does more redirects until eventually you arrive at the URL above.

In ICS, you need to manually select the browser (and ignore the Foursquare native app) on each redirect to get to the page that has the problem. That is not a very logical thing to do...and so the problem is less priority on ICS.

On Gingerbread, you don't get that option, the browser goes through all the redirects and you end up at the web page mentioned above. Then clicking the link offers the Foursquare app and it fails to checkin.

Is there any known workaround for this?

Comment: Could be a bug indeed, but is not a programming question?

Comment: This happens on (at least) Android ICS 4.40 Stock browser and Chrome Beta on ICS 4.04.

Comment: I guess the programming question is: Is there a workaround or fix using a different url, url parameters, JavaScript, so I can send users to a page to do checkin and IF they have the native app installed they can us it, and if not then they can do web checkin.

Answer (score -1):

This is not a bug. It is the wrong URL for triggering the Venue Activity. Use the following URL instead, as described in the [Foursquare developer documentation](https://developer.foursquare.com/resources/client):

http://m.foursquare.com/venue/VENUE_ID

In your case: http://m.foursquare.com/venue/4e89646eb634306116691c16

Comment: In fact, this is the url I use originally. When you open it in Android stock browser (ICS 4.04) after a couple of re-directs you end up at the url https://foursquare.com/mobile/v/bcntouch/4e89646eb634306116691c16 I specified above, where the HTML page is served from.

Comment: Very strange. The Intend is triggered for me, when I click on the original URL.

Comment: But if you chose web browser (through each redirect) until you get to the page and then click the "Check-in" link, does it work then?

Comment: Now, I've narrowed down the case where this behavior is seen more. In fact in ICS, you need to manually select the browser (and ignore the Foursquare app) on each redirect to get to the page that has the problem (not a very logical thing to do...).    But on Gingerbread, you don't get that option, the browser goes through all the redirects and you end up at the web page mentioned above. Then clicking the link offers the Foursquare app and it fails to checkin.